# PHP Include DB Conn - Password not accessible

Tags: php

I have a strange include file problem. I'm hoping its a simple fix due to being a 2-day-old, PHP noob.

I'm simply trying to include DB credentials in to my parent script, like this:

**db-conn.php**

```
<?php
$dbUsername = "xxx";
$dbPassword = "xxx";
$dbHostname = "localhost";
?>
```

**parent.php**

```
<?php
include("c:/inetpub/vhosts/mydomain.net/php-private/db-conn.php");

//echo $dbPassword;
//echo $dbUsername;

$dbHandle = mysql_connect($dbHostname, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die("Unable to load page content due to a connection fault.");
unset ($dbHostname, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);

echo "Connected to MySQL<br><br>";
?>
```

But I'm getting this error:

**Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**

What is strange about this (for me) is that I can echo the username and hostname successfully but I cannot echo the password, it's empty. Yet if I go to my include file, copy the password from 'dbPassword' and paste it inline on my parent page, it works. This proves my password is correct, the username and hostname ARE included, I just can't access my password variable!

Can somebody pleeeease put me straight here. I've already pulled my hair out tonight with open_basedir and permissions for this include file!! *_*

**UPDATE - **

Problem solved, please see my answer below.

Comment: Try commenting the unset line.

Comment: Try to bring those variables inside `parent.php` and see if it works.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy: Tried this still no password.

Comment: @EdwinDrood: The script works fine if I bring the variables to parent.php. Just not from include.

Comment: Then try using global. `global $dbPassword`

Comment: why don't you make the connection in db-conn.php itself?

Comment: @RishiKalia: I probably will but I still need this answering otherwise there will be suicide! :)

Comment: someone may yell at you: don't use `mysql_*` as it is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: I don't think my include url is correct, I'm not getting anything from the include file. I cannot understand why echo dbUsername works though. Maybe this page cached from earlier testing?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for wasting time guys. I found the problem. I didn't give FTP users write access to the `\php-private\` folder I created before the root, so when I was changing the file and uploading it, if I actually checked the FTP logs I would have seen that it failed with 'Access Denied'. I changed permissions and kapow, my CURRENT include file works fine! What a pleb!

Answer (score 0):

If db-conn.php and parent.php are in the same folder, you can directly use

```
include ('db-conn.php');
```

And I'm not sure about the use of `unset ($dbHostname, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);`

Also it's saying that no password has been set. So maybe you should use empty string for the $dbPassword variable `$dbpassword = '';`

Answer (score 0):

```
Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

is simply telling you that you are not giving password to mysql_connect()
You can 1. Check if you are including the correct db-conn.php file. 
2. Add this to the top of your db-conn.php

```
 global $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbHostname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using 127.0.0.1 as a hostname. The problem is that sometimes PHP doesn't accept localhost as host, because of a missing line in the host.ini file.